# Slide text search box is overwritten

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, liferay-theme

I'm doing a search box slide. What I need is that when you click on the magnifying glass, move the slide the "Castilian", text and that it is not fixed text and sarch see box below. It's possible? this is the best I could do ...

[My code](http://www.bootply.com/gav8Crvjtu)

Comment: so you want to slide the CASTELLANO word also to left?

Comment: @Leothelion Hello! if you left that moves the pair of slide ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this css. This worked.

```
#wrap {
  margin: 39px 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  /*float: right;*/
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

input[type="text"] {
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 55px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-weight: 100;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #555;
  padding: 3px;
  padding-right: 60px;
  width: 0px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: none;
  z-index: 3;
  transition: width .4s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.795, 0.000, 1.000);
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="text"]:focus:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB;
}

input[type="text"]:focus form {
  width: 700px;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  width: 700px;
  z-index: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB;
  cursor: text;
}
input[type="submit"] {
  height: 67px;
  width: 63px;
  display: inline-block;
  color:red;
  /*float: right;*/
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,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) center center no-repeat;
  text-indent: -10000px;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.4;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: opacity .4s ease;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```